# delete ECS task for old revision - only use new revision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

As you can see I have task definition for revision 4 and a task definition for revision 5. I want permanently stop running 4, and only run 5:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So in other words, the task that is PROVISIONING - I only want that one. The task that is RUNNING - I don't want that one to run anymore. How to achieve this?

Comment: Just be patient, generally... Fargate tasks take a little time to setup. It will eventually hit running state. If it's a web task with a load balancer, the older task will have to "drain" first before it's stopped. That usually takes about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the scenario and it went well for me. So what I think is you need to dig further under the hood.

Your task is in provisioning state which I believe is related to your environment and not related to your task, service or cluster.

From the AWS Documentation :

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-lifecycle.html

```
**PROVISIONING**
Amazon ECS has to perform additional steps before the task is launched. For example, for tasks that use the awsvpc network mode, the elastic network interface needs to be provisioned.
```

You might want to check below things to start debugging :

1. Cloudformation template that ECS use to provision your resources.
2. Try looking into your VPC if anything got changed since the last deployment.
3. Security Groups, IAM Roles to find out if anything blocking your resource creation.